# Pattern: adjective/noun + in + ing

Tags: prepositions

everyone. I have a question regarding the usage of "in" in this pattern:

```
Adjective/noun + in + V-ing
```

Like in this sentence:

1. «Light takes such a long time in crossing the enormous distances and getting to us.»

But, I was wondering if it could work without "in":

2. «Light takes such a long time crossing the enormous distances and getting to us.»

Or, even with infinitive:

3. «Light takes such a long time to cross the enormous distances and getting to us.»

I would like to know how to use this patten, in what context and what rules I should follow to use it correctly.

I've been searching on the internet, but there is little information about this topic and it's not really helpful. Here are some other examples I found:

1. This NPO plays a central role in proposing environmental policies.
2. He's taking a long time in making that pastry

Thanks you in advanced, I'd be really thankful if you help me understand it.

Comment: All of your examples work. What is it that you have a question about in them?

Comment: Hi, David. The thing is that I didn't know that "in" could be use in that structure. I want to know how to use that pattern: adjective/noun + in + V-ing.

Comment: You're using it correctly. Not sure if there's a hard and fast rule for it.

Comment: Do all of them mean the same?

Comment: To my eye, yes. I'm certain we could spend hours trying to come up with an example that doesn't. But, you're doing fine.

Comment: Ok, so, every time I come across with a sentence that has noun + -ing I could put "in" between them. Is it more formal?  Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm going to give a more formal answer.

Comment: Thank you! That's all a needed to hear haha, and yes, Spanish is my native language. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In short: your example sentences all work fine.  The presence or absence of *in* makes little difference to their meaning and is largely styling.

As far as a rule goes, there's only one I'd suggest.  Save this construct for adverbial clauses that use the gerund form.

> I'm very influential in suggesting things to the boss.
>
> I enjoy taking my time in crossing the street.

Don't use it after noun phrases that include a gerund.

> *Frog jumping* is my favorite betting sport.

Comment: Thanks, David, for your help. Now I understand it.